# Behavior and Preference Differences in Xcode 4 vs Xcode 3

Tags: xcode, preferences, xcode4

I just upgraded to Xcode 4 (from 3.2.4) and while there are a lot of behavior/preference changes I need to get used to, I'd like to get a couple issues handled sooner rather than later.

Can I exclude the delimiters when balancing delimiters? In v3.x, you could balance delimiters and the selection would exclude the enclosing braces. Is that possible with v4?

Is there an equivalent to the advanced find/search available in v3? Used to ctrl-click on a symbol and select search in project which opened a new search window. You could also define different search sets to use when searching. I can't find any similar behavior in v4.

Finally, does anyone know if the Apple developer forums are available to users who have only registered as a developer (but not joined)?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you can't get access to Apple developer forums there's a very good mailing list for Xcode users: Xcode-users@lists.apple.com - several Apple engineers hang out on this list.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Help menu in Xcode 4 there is an option for Xcode User Guide which covers what you can do with Xcode 4. I have been through it and it seems pretty light so far so it may not have what you need, but it is a good place to start.

I also did a search in Help and quickly found that you can change this setting with a checkbox in Preferences under Text Editing. I've included a screenshot with the option highlighted below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip Brennan, unfortunately I think that's just for inserting the closing brace of control structures like for-loops, functions and such. It doesn't affect balancing behavior.

I've searched for the option in the help and it doesn't mention any way to change it.